Query with filter on jsonb array looking for nested key/value
I have the following table:
create table payment_records (
  id         uuid        not null primary key,
  record     jsonb       not null,
  created_at timestamptz default now() not null
);

A typical entry would include the following json for the record column
{
    "records": [{
            "recordId": "5f5d8e39-1b57-4a05-9bdd-cb5e957768fc",
            "payment": {
                "booked": true,
                "errors": [],
                "return": null,
                "status": "Processed",
                "latestStatusChangedTimestamp": "2024-10-30T07:43:40.5+00:00"
            },
            "timestamp": "2024-10-30T07:43:50.557939Z"
        }, {
            "recordId": "c3e049e8-a3e3-4e80-be63-bdf58e121c8a",
            "payment": {
                "booked": true,
                "errors": [],
                "return": null,
                "status": "Processed",
                "latestStatusChangedTimestamp": "2024-10-30T07:43:40.5+00:00"
            },
            "timestamp": "2024-10-30T07:43:50.557941Z"
        }, {
            "recordId": "abf35109-7d5f-4ba3-9f6e-2c6d1a305134",
            "payment": {
                "booked": true,
                "errors": [],
                "return": null,
                "status": "Processed",
                "latestStatusChangedTimestamp": "2024-10-30T07:43:40.5+00:00"
            },
            "timestamp": "2024-10-30T07:43:50.5579416Z"
        }
    ]
}

I need a query to return any entry where the recordId matched my search criteria eg recordId='abf35109-7d5f-4ba3-9f6e-2c6d1a305134'
Tried a few queries with no luck.

By "where the recordId matched", you mean "where any nested recordId matched"? Please always declare your version of Postgres.

Assuming the internal structure of the jsonb column is stable as demonstrated, a filter with the @> can do it:
SELECT *
FROM   payment_records
WHERE  record @> '{"records": [{"recordId":"abf35109-7d5f-4ba3-9f6e-2c6d1a305134"}]}';

Or, in recent versions, using the @? operator:
WHERE  record @? '$.records[*] ? (@."recordId" == "abf35109-7d5f-4ba3-9f6e-2c6d1a305134")';

fiddle
Either can use an index. See:

Index for finding an element in a JSON array
Find rows containing a key in a JSONB array of records

